# Remove PHP email validation

Tags: php, css

How can I remove the ugly error caused by PHP? I don't know if the webhost is causing it or if I can fix it with PHP/CSS, I have no email validation in my code [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhWRJ.png)

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" name="email">
          <label for="email" data-error="Geen geldig e-mailadres" data-success="Dit e-mailadres word alleen gebruikt om een antwoord te versturen.">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>


<?php
error_reporting(0);
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'my@mail.com';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "/n fill in all fields";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if( empty($errors))

{

$to = $myemail;

$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";

$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".

" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".

"Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";

$headers = "From: $myemail\n";

$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

//redirect to the 'thank you' page

header('Location: bedankt.html');

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the full code for the email part, `error_reporting(0);` does not seem to work for the described problem

Comment: check your html validation

Comment: The input is probably of type mail. Change it to text. This has to do with HTML, not PHP.

Comment: Is there a way of not displaying the error while keeping the email type?

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Html Email

From

```
<input type="email" >
```

To

```
<input type="text" >
```

Comment: If I change it to text, the red error bar from my framework is not displaying as well but I would like to keep that, is there another option to not display that error?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, changing the mail type to text in your HTML will remove the validation. You mentioned you want to keep the field type as email. To disable the the HTML5 validation, you need to add `novalidate` to your form.

As in:

```
<form method="post" action="/yourAction" novalidate>...</form>
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp)